# PHP Sessions slow down the ttfb by at least 30 seconds

Tags: php, apache, session

I encountered the following problem:

I have a very simple script which forwards the user to this login script via `POST`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["job"] = "admin";
$_SESSION["login"] = true;
$_SESSION["email"] = "email@example.com";
$_SESSION["username"] = "example";
session_write_close(); # I added this because it was recommendet to solve my problem, which it unforunately doesn't do.
header("Location: ../home");
```

As soon as this script is executed **everything** is blocked which executes `session_start();` in its script. The `TTFB` is always above 60s

The only fix is to restart apache via `service apache2 restart` every time.

My `Apache2`and `PHP` are clean installed *today* on an absolute fresh server, everything was configured according to the official instructions. Additionally I encounter this problem on every other server I ran my script on.

What could be a solution? I've searched the internet for days now...

Comment: What happens if you add before `session_...close` `die();`. Does that change the TTFB? If that's not the case add right after `header` an `exit;`. This is recommended anyway since there might be unwanted code that will be executed as well.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 yes it does! Why? I code PHP for about 5 years now and never had this

Comment: "yes it does!" To what do you refer that and I suppose it reduces the TTFB? The `die` or `exit`?

Comment: the ttfb is gone, almost 0s - i used die

Comment: Glad to know. Well, I suppose you placed the `exit` / `die` right after the redirect. It seems like there is more code executed right after the `header` statement. Cannot say that for sure as I do not know your code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As read from the above comments it seems like there is further code after the `header` statement since working with `exit` solves your issue. So that people crossing this post quickly see the solution I add this answer.

To avoid this unwanted behaviour it's a good habit to place a `die` or `exit` after the statement.